# jQuery – add class to every second item with same class then reset if interrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm thinking this has probably been asked a thousand times, but I'm unsure what to search for (I had a good look but couldn't find anything) so this is what I am wondering...

I have a simple container/element setup of the following:

```
<div class="chronology-container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 large each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
</div>
```

**Now what I'm looking to do is add a class to every second of the `small` class items. So ideally my output, for example, would be:**

```
<div class="chronology-container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small shift each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small shift each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 large each-chronology"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using a few setups, the most hopeful was:

```
$('.chronology-container .each-chronology:nth-of-type(2n)').addClass('shift');
```

But this added a the class `shift` to the element after the `large` element, which is wrong as it should only add it to the second item of `small` so assumes they will be groups in two.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by reset

Comment: @ArunPJohny I guess my thinking was that it's every 2 items until it reaches a 'large' or non 'small' classed item so it would 'reset' and start again? Perhaps a bad explanation.

Comment: do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/4fvqaos1/ ?

Comment: @Learner That is what I was looking for... must be Monday morning killing it for me. Thanks. Feel free to submit as answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
$('.chronology-container .each-chronology.small').not('.small + .small').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(.small)').filter(':even').addClass('shift')
});
```

```css
.small {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.chronology-container > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
.chronology-container > .small.shift {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.chronology-container > .small.shift2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chronology-container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 large each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 large each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 small each-chronology"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:-

```
$('.chronology-container .each-chronology.small:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('shift');
```

Update:-

```
$('.chronology-container .each-chronology.small:even:not(:first)').addClass('shift');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fvqaos1/)

Comment: Actually, I've skipped something here... it needs to start from second item... not first item. So the `shift` class should be on every second starting from the second.

Comment: Yeah that is what I had but it adds a class to the last item, but it shouldn't because it's every second item...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct, except that you are using the wrong class to identify the elements. The class `each-chronology` is common to large element also. Instead of using `each-chronology`, use `small` as the class selector.

Try using the following solution:

```
$('.chronology-container .small:nth-of-type(2n)').addClass('shift');
```

** OR **

```
$('.chronology-container .small.each-chronology:nth-child(2n)').addClass('shift');
```